# Не выполнен шаг задания SQL Агента

Tags: sql-server

Шаг задания (CmdExec). Программка простая на C#: загружает html и сохраняет в файл. Входных данных нет. Сайт и путь к файлу указан в самой программке. Если запускать из командной строки, то всё окей, в файле появляется скачанный html.
А вот при использовании агента sql server происходит исключение на этапе помещения html в папку: "System.Net.WebException: Исключение во время запроса WebClient. --> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Отказано в доступе по пути "путь к папке, куда надо поместить html".

Что с этим делать?

Comment: Значит не хватает прав.

Comment: В строке вы ее запускаете со своими правам, а агент со своими. Его прав на запись в папку может не хватать. Другой вариант - в программе указан относительный путь, а не абсолютный. При запуске агентом текущая работая директория может быть вообще не, которую вы ожидаете, и уже там прав не хватает.

Comment: @teran, а как решить проблему?

Comment: для начала дать sql агенту права на запись в папку, куда сохраняется файл

Comment: @teran как это можно сделать?

Comment: Смотрите из под какой учётки запущена соответствующая служба, эту учётную запись добавить в права, на вкладке "безопасность" папки. Как-то так.

Comment: @nick_n_a где надо посмотреть учётку?

Comment: SQL Server configuration manager запускаешь, выбираешь агента, смотришь учетку