# Права агента SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Как дать агенту права на доступ к папке?

Comment: Лучше не создавать короткие вопросы, как вопрос из комментария  в связке https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/747059/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b3-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-sql-%d0%90%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0?noredirect=1 лучше коментарием задавать.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно дать права учетной записи, от имени которой запущен SQL Agent. Желательно также выдать права учетной записи, от имени которой запущен SQL Server.